# What is the rule of thumb to choose proper encoding for dealing Japanese characters in python

Tags: python, character-encoding, cjk

I have been opening and rebuilding 2000+ HTML files with python bs4, and the contents of all of them are written in Japanese.

The thing is, I cannot find a proper rule-of-thumb-encoding for those files.
I made try-excepts for the following encodings, but there are still errors.

```
utf-8, utf-16, utf-32, shift-jis, cp1252, euc
```

Nothing worked without errors and there were even files that I cannot open at all(but it opens in text editors, though! I tried saving with utf-8, but it never worked too!!!)

I am completely exhausted to find out how can I let my code run without me.

Can anybody help me? What is the error-free encoding to open / write Japanese?

Comment: Some text editors will show you the encoding that they are using in their status bar.  Otherwise you can use packages like chardet or charset-normalizer to guess the encoding of file contents.

Comment: Look at HTML with ASCII editor. If you can read the tags, you are not in UTF-16 or UTF-32 (or any 16-bit encoding). But so you can check the encoding (if should be written in the HTML header. Else: look Wikipedia for Japaneese encoding: there should be not many more left (not 7bit ASCII compatible)

Comment: To *write* Japanese, UTF-8 should always be sufficient.  If you have an example where it isn't, please share.

Comment: You kind of need to provide more details here. 2000 files is potentially 2000 different encodings (although realistically, more like 3, because they're either going to be UTF8, Shift-JIS, or EUC-JP), is there a reason to assume they all use the same encoding? Also, do they _declare_ their encoding using a `<meta>` tag? Are you tapping into that? As for the files that failed: after opening one in a text editor and cycling through the encodings, which one actually made the content look like Japanese?